# How to ignore certain rows while looping over pandas dataframe using iterrows

Tags: python, pandas

i am trying to loop over a pandas dataframe using iterrows. However, if i reach a certain predetermined row, i was to just skip over that row and now perform the next calculations and just continue to the next row. However, i am very unsure on how to do so.

This is what i've trie so far.

```py
dish_one = unimp_features.iloc[235]
dish_two = unimp_features.iloc[621]
dish_three = unimp_features.iloc[831]

for index, row in unimp_features.iterrows():
    if row == dish_one or row == dish_two or row == dish_three:
        continue
    else:
        df_unimportant.loc[index, 'cos_one'] = 1 - spatial.distance.cosine(dish_one, row)
        df_unimportant.loc[index, 'cos_two'] = 1 - spatial.distance.cosine(dish_two, row)
        df_unimportant.loc[index, 'cos_three'] = 1 - spatial.distance.cosine(dish_three, row)
```

The goal is to ignore the row where dish_one, dish_two & dish_three is present, and just go to the next row and continue the next calculations further down in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

I had to use a Series function called Series.equals(Series)

So end result is:

```py
for index, row in unimp_features.iterrows():
    if row.equals(dish_one) | row.equals(dish_two) | row.equals(dish_three):
        continue
    else:
        df_unimportant.loc[index, 'cos_one'] = 1 - spatial.distance.cosine(dish_one, row)
        df_unimportant.loc[index, 'cos_two'] = 1 - spatial.distance.cosine(dish_two, row)
        df_unimportant.loc[index, 'cos_three'] = 1 - spatial.distance.cosine(dish_three, row)
```